# Coldfusion Need Help Parent / Child Dynamic Menu

Tags: coldfusion, navigation

Basically I want to have each child menu only display on the parent menu ID. But so far, all I can get is all of the child `li`'s connecting to any parent menu I set up.

Here is a diagram to explain how the menu is displaying right now:

- Home

  About > Employment & Mobile (I only want employment to display)

  Services > Employment & Mobile (I only want mobile to display)
- Contact

So the queries output the following variables from the database

- pg_LinkName
- pg_MenuTitle
- pg_ParentMenu (the name of the parent menu),
- pg_MenuType (a yes/no to say if it is a parent/sub menu),
- pg_SubMenu (a yes/no to specify whether the menu is a parent menu or not)

I want to know if there's a way to connect the child to the parent dynamically. eg. If I choose to attach a page to a parent, it only shows on that parent in the drop down.

Here are my queries:

```
<cfquery name="qry_GetMenu" datasource="#request.dsn#"> 
    SELECT *
    FROM tbl_pages 
    WHERE pg_MenuType = TRUE AND pg_Display = TRUE AND pg_AutoMenu = TRUE AND pg_Horiz_VertMenu = TRUE
    ORDER BY pg_sort
</cfquery>

<cfquery name="qry_GetSubMenus" datasource="#request.dsn#"> 
    SELECT *
    FROM tbl_pages 
    WHERE pg_MenuType = FALSE 
    ORDER BY pg_sort
</cfquery>

<cfquery name="qry_SubMenu" datasource="#request.dsn#"> 
    SELECT *
    FROM tbl_pages
    WHERE pg_SubMenu = TRUE
    ORDER BY pg_sort
</cfquery>
```

And this is what I have for the menu:

```
<ul class="menu">     
    <cfoutput query="qry_GetMenu">
        <li <cfif cgi.path_info contains "#pg_LinkName#"> class="current-menu-parent"</cfif>>
        <a href="#systemurl#/index.cfm/#pg_LinkName#/">#pg_MenuTitle#</a>
        <cfif pg_SubMenu gt 0>
            <ul class="sub-menu">
                <cfloop query="qry_GetSubMenus">
                    <li><a href="#systemurl#/index.cfm/#pg_ParentMenu#/#pg_LinkName#/">#pg_MenuTitle#</a></li>
                </cfloop>
            </ul>
        </cfif>
        </li>
    </cfoutput>
</ul>
```

Comment: Can you be a bit clear about ur query..

Comment: Just updated some more information hopefully it's a bit more clearer!

Comment: where r u ending ur loop and update code ..correctly

Comment: dynamically add..a class to each of the menu and use jquery to show the menu related data for each of the links

Comment: The loop ends after the sub menu li i organised it a bit better if that helps, so if i add another column in the database that pulls in a unique class to each menu item how can i filter which li element goes where? Can you show/link me for more information on the jquery coding required thanks for your help so far!

Comment: can you scope your outputs? It's nearly impossible to read without proper scoping.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I'm understanding correctly, you only want to display the assigned children under the corresponding parent, and your code is currently displaying the child elements under every parent displayed?

With your current code, you would need to move one of your queries in line

```
<ul class="menu">     
<cfoutput query="qry_GetMenu">
    <li <cfif cgi.path_info contains "#pg_LinkName#"> class="current-menu-parent"</cfif>>
    <a href="#systemurl#/index.cfm/#pg_LinkName#/">#pg_MenuTitle#</a>
    <cfif pg_SubMenu gt 0>
        <ul class="sub-menu">
        <!---moved inline to add additional conditional pg_ParentMenu clause--->
        <cfquery name="qry_GetSubMenus" datasource="#request.dsn#">  
            SELECT * FROM q WHERE pg_MenuType = 0 AND pg_ParentMenu = '#pg_ParentMenu#'
        </cfquery>
            <cfloop query="qry_GetSubMenus">
                <li><a href="#systemurl#/index.cfm/#pg_ParentMenu#/#pg_LinkName#/">#pg_MenuTitle#</a></li>
            </cfloop>
        </ul>
    </cfif>
    </li>
</cfoutput>
```

This would allow the query to be filtered specifically to the current parent menu as opposed to all parent menus. If it is a huge data set, this will become pretty inefficient. 
There are lots of options at that point (perform the loops and assign to another object like an array of structs that has the keys for parent and children, with the children being another array, or re-working the database to make the sub-menus relational, etc.).

Hope that is moving in the right direction.

Comment: Thanks that worked! i had to change a few variables around but i got it !